# One to Zero or One Relationship, Using Subtypes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a large application that has many drop down fields in the system that have just a small set of values. It's not really worth it to have a table for each of these values and a separate page to handle crud for each of the drop down types. WHat I did is make a DropDowns table that has a discriminator column to discern which type of drop down it is.

I define each type in the code by just creating a class that derives from the drop down class.

My CRUD manager is able to use reflection to allow the user to add a value to any of the drop downs.

So far so good.

Now I want to be able to EXTEND a particular drop down, so that it can have properties that the other drop downs don't have.

For instance, the list of payment terms. I'd like to add a field for the deposit percentage, so that I can use that to calculate the deposit.

My goal is to have all of the values stored in a single table, similar to the way drop down values are.

In SQL, I would just have a table called DropDownExtendedProperties with fields: DropDownID, PropertyName, PropertyValue with the DropDownID linking the Extended Property to the dropdown value that it accompanies.

In C# / EF I was able to get the correct database structure using 1 to 0 or 1, BUT once I make subtypes of DropDownExtendedProperty, the dropdown type makes a direct relationship to that table for the subtype.

I tried fooling with a one to many but I don't see a way out of this other than just pulling the types that need extended properties out of the DropDown table and making their own table & CRUD. I understand that at this point that is actually the simpler solution, but I think what I'm trying to do should be possible and I just can't figure out how.

I've included some code below, but I have tried the relationship a few different ways, and I am posting the most recent attempt.

```
public class DropDownExtendedProperty
{
    [Key]
    public int PropertyID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("DropDown")]
    public int DropDownID { get; set; }

    public virtual DropDown DropDown { get; set; }

    public int? IntValue { get; set; }
    public string StringValue { get; set; }
    public FieldType FieldType { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateValue { get; set; }
    public float? MoneyValue { get; set; }
}

public class DropDown
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Value { get; set; }

    public virtual List<DropDownExtendedProperty> ExtendedProperties { get; set; }

}

public class PaymentTerms : DropDown
{
    public virtual DaysToPay DaysToPay { get; set; }
}

public class DaysToPay : DropDownExtendedProperty
{

}

public enum FieldType
{
    Date,
    String,
    Int,
    Money
}

modelBuilder.Entity<DropDownExtendedProperty>()
            .HasRequired(a => a.DropDown)
            .WithMany();
```

My goal with this is to be able to define SINGLE value for each DropDown that has a specific type THROUGH the more abstract DropDownExtendedProperty. So in our case, the PaymentTerms dropdown value of "Net30" can have an accompanying int value in the DaysToPay field which I can use in the code for calculations.

Comment: `DropDown` is the drop down type, like `Payment Terms`, `Order Types`, `Delivery Types`? `DropDownExtendedProperty` is the option values for each `DropDown`, like for `Payment Terms` the values are `2 Weeks`, `30 Days` and `6 Months`? One (DropDown) to many (DropDownExtendedProperty) that works fine, I don't see the problem here..

Comment: No, the DropDown type contains its values. So the net30, net60, COD values are all stored in the DropDown. What I'm trying to do is for certain drop down types, (PaymentTerms is only one example of a drop down) add an ADDITIONAL field that allows me to have another value other than the choice that user picks in the drop down. So when they select "Net30" as the terms, the system will know that in 30 days, this payment is due.

Comment: I'm starting to think this might be impossible with EF. It would need to use the DropDownID + the Discriminator column to learn what the DaysToPay property was.